# How to download attachments from Outlook mail using java without using server settings?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Hi I am trying to use java to download attachment's from the mail which is received on the current date.

But while checking for IMAP or POP3 server details to connect it shown as not available. Can any one tell me how to overcome this issue is there any other way to connect?
[image]

I was some what able to connect but now i am getting below error

OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [KJGHFUFJHGKLJYOYRGFJHGFYFTHGFJYTFYJTFAwADEAQwBBADAAMAA1ADIALgBJAE4ARABQAFIARAAwADEALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
B0 CAPABILITY

CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
B0 OK CAPABILITY completed.

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN

DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: XOAUTH2

DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=name@outlook.com, password= non-null

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed

DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: B1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.

Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.

**Below is the code I used**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import javax.mail.Flags;
    import javax.mail.Folder;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Store;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.Part;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
    import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;
    import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentInfo;
    import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentInfoUtil;
    import com.j256.simplemagic.ContentType;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    public class test2 {
    
        public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            //String imapProtocol = System.getgetImapSsl() != null && server.getImapSsl() == true ? "imaps" : "imap";
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
            props.put("mail.mime.base64.ignoreerrors", "true");
            
            //props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");
             
            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props
                    , 
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication("NAME@OUTLOOK.com", "PASSWORD");// Specify the Username and the PassWord
                        }
                });
            String test = "Workwork112233!";
            System.out.println(test);
            mailSession.setDebug(true);
           Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
            store.connect( "outlook.office365.com","NAME@OUTLOOK.com", "PASSWORD");
                
    
          
    
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    
            System.out.println("Total Message:" + folder.getMessageCount());
            System.out.println("Unread Message:" + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
    
            Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
    
            for (Message mail : messages) {
                if (!mail.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
    
                    System.out.println("***************************************************");
                    System.out.println("MESSAGE : \n");
    
                    System.out.println("Subject: " + mail.getSubject());
                    System.out.println("From: " + mail.getFrom()[0]);
                    System.out.println("To: " + mail.getAllRecipients()[0]);
                    System.out.println("Date: " + mail.getReceivedDate());
                    System.out.println("Size: " + mail.getSize());
                    System.out.println("Flags: " + mail.getFlags());
                    System.out.println("ContentType: " + mail.getContentType());
                    System.out.println("Body: \n" + getEmailBody(mail));
                   // System.out.println("Has Attachments: " + hasAttachments(mail));
    
                }
            }
            
              
            }
        
    
        public static  String getEmailBody(Message email) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    
            String line, emailContentEncoded;
            StringBuffer bufferEmailContentEncoded = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(email.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                bufferEmailContentEncoded.append(line);
            }
    
            System.out.println("**************************************************");
    
            System.out.println(bufferEmailContentEncoded);
    
            System.out.println("**************************************************");
    
            emailContentEncoded = bufferEmailContentEncoded.toString();
    
            if (email.getContentType().toLowerCase().contains("multipart/related")) {
    
                emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(emailContentEncoded.indexOf("base64") + 6);
                emailContentEncoded = emailContentEncoded.substring(0, emailContentEncoded.indexOf("Content-Type") - 1);
    
                System.out.println(emailContentEncoded);
    
                String emailContentDecoded = new String(new Base64().decode(emailContentEncoded.toString().getBytes()));
                return emailContentDecoded;
            }
    
            return emailContentEncoded;
    
        }}
```

Comment: No, I dont think there is any other way. You need any of those settings to connect an external client to your outlook mail server.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question, however, is not really a code related question, but more on how to use Outlook APIs to download messages.

Comment: Hi @SMA  I was some what able to connect but getting the above error

Comment: HI @dovetalk I was some what able to connect but getting the above error